# Is there any possibility of getting the meet link directly in the API

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

Is there any possibility of getting the meet link directly in the API, without creating google calendar.

I read official Google Workspace API documentation but no information there in the document to get meet link directly.

Please update the latest and most accurate details regarding any new features or endpoints related to Google Meet links.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem to be possible to do what you are seeking (**at the time of writing this answer**).

As you mentioned, you can use [Google's Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events#conferencing) and create an event and add to it a Meet link.

But if you look [here](https://developers.google.com/meet), which is the Google Meet API documentation, the only available option there is their live sharing SDK.

Furthermore, in [Google's APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer), when you look up Meet, there are no results.